# connecting several database using tFileInputProperties in Talend

Tags: talend

I'm completely new to talend and currently I need to build a job that reads params values like

1. Database Name
2. Server Name
3. Host Name
4. Password
5. username

From a property file and passed those values in a tPostgresqlConnection Component.

This is what I have try so far

tFileInputProperties -------> tContextLoad ------> tPostgresqlConnection

Talend Job Image:
[image: Talend Job Image]

Problem is the job is taking only one database connection instead of looping for all databases connection that I have defined in the file properties.

Can someone advice how i can create a Job that will loop params values on the tPostgresqlConnection component?

Comment: But you only read one file ? How is your properties defined exactly ? `ContextLoad` expect a schema like `key/value`. So you should have 6 row in your file to define the connection properties. If you have more that 6rows, the first values will be erased by the last one. You need more than one file, then use a `tFileList` to iterate the files. Then, I am not sure this is a good idea to use the same `connection` component, you can't close all of them ...

Comment: what does key/value represent in the ContextLoad component?
And my properties file contains below info :
serveur_1 = localhost
port_1 = 5432
DB_Name_1 = Test
schema_1 = public
user_1 = postgres
pwrd_1 = X
server_2 = 127.0.0.1
port_2 = 5432
DB_Name_2 = DWH
schema_2 = public
user_2 = postgres
pwrd_2 = Y

Comment: I invite you to take a look at [talend tLoadContext](https://help.talend.com/reader/wDRBNUuxk629sNcI0dNYaA/xH2TyYr_AmQnKwOYlqVCvA) documentation. The key is the context name, and the value is the value to set. So you should jave a file with the keys use in your `tPostgreConnection`

Comment: I have check tLoadContext documentation and I have a plan.
I will implement the job with the following logic :

1. create different properties file for each database.
2. Use a tFileList to loop data

tFileList ----> tfileProperties ----> tContextLoad -----> tPostgresqlConnection

Comment: And how are you expecting to use the connection ? To execute queries on a DB, you need to specify the component used to open the connection, meaning it will only hold one connection instance. You won't be able to use one of the connection opened in the same component. (and you are probably going to leak connection...)

Comment: I was thinking to create different properties file for each database then use a tFileList to loop those files values in the tPostgresqlConnection...but its not working....do you have any idea about how I can implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a properties file per database connection, and in each file you define your connection parameters :

```
server=myServer
port=myPort
user=myUser
password=myPassword
...
```

(Make sur your parameters have the same keys across files)

Then you can do something like this :

```
tFileList -- Iterate -- tFileInputProperties -- Main -- tContextLoad -- OnComponentOk --  tRunJob
```

the `tContextLoad` component will populate the context parameters (which need to exist in your main job and child job).

In the tRunJob, you encapsulate your job logic : connect to your database using your connection parameters (server, port, user..etc) passed down from the parent job, do what you need to do, and close your connection at the end of your job.

Make sure to check the option "`Transmit whole context`" in your tRunJob component settings.

Of course you can do it all in a single job using OnSubjobOk links, but I find this more readable (and easily maintainable)